# Apex test failure: ChatterAnswersEscalationTriggerTest

Tags: apex

I'm receiving an error during deployment from a managed apex test class - ChatterAnswersEscalationTriggerTest.  My code is listed below.  Need the corrected code to update the test class.

> Error: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to
>   SObject  Stack Trace:
>   Class.ChatterAnswersEscalationTriggerTest.validateQuestionEscalation:
>   line 17, column 1

Pretty sure the error has to do with this line in the test class: 
Case ca = [SELECT Origin, CommunityId, Subject, Description from Case where QuestionId =: q.Id];

Apex Test Class

```
@isTest 
private class ChatterAnswersEscalationTriggerTest2 { 
static testMethod void validateQuestionEscalation() { 
String questionTitle = 'questionTitle'; 
String questionBody = 'questionBody'; 
Community[] c = [SELECT Id from Community]; 
// We cannot create a question without a community 
if (c.size() == 0) { return; } 
String communityId = c[0].Id; 
Question q = new Question(); 
q.Title = questionTitle; 
q.Body = questionBody; 
q.CommunityId = communityId; 
insert(q); 
q.Priority = 'high'; 
update(q); 
Case ca = [SELECT Origin, CommunityId, Subject, Description from Case where QuestionId =: q.Id]; 
// Test that escaltion trigger correctly escalate the question to a case 
System.assertEquals(questionTitle, ca.Subject); 
System.assertEquals(questionBody, ca.Description); 
System.assertEquals('Chatter Answers', ca.Origin); 
System.assertEquals(communityId, ca.CommunityId); 
} 
}
```

Apex Trigger
chatter_answers_question_escalation_to_case_trigger

```
trigger chatter_answers_question_escalation_to_case_trigger on Question (after update) {
for (Question q: Trigger.new) {
    try {
        if (q.Priority == 'high' && (q.Cases == null || q.Cases.size() == 0) && Trigger.oldMap.get(q.id).Priority != 'high') {
            q = [select Id, Title, Body, CommunityId, createdById, createdBy.AccountId, createdBy.ContactId from Question where Id = :q.Id];
            Case newCase = new Case();
            if(q.title=='negtativeTitle' && test.isrunningtest()){
                newCase = new Case(Origin='Chatter Answers', QuestionId=q.Id, CommunityId=q.CommunityId, Description = (q.Body == null? null: q.Body.stripHtmlTags()), AccountId=q.CreatedBy.AccountId, ContactId=q.CreatedBy.ContactId,id=q.id);
            }
            newCase = new Case(Origin='Chatter Answers', OwnerId=q.CreatedById, QuestionId=q.Id, CommunityId=q.CommunityId, Subject=q.Title, Description = (q.Body == null? null: q.Body.stripHtmlTags()), AccountId=q.CreatedBy.AccountId, ContactId=q.CreatedBy.ContactId);
            insert newCase;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String subjectText = 'Case Escalation exception in site ' + Site.getName();
        String bodyText = 'Case Escalation on Question having ID: ' + q.Id + ' has failed with the following message: ' + e.getMessage() +
            '\n\nStacktrace: ' + e.getStacktraceString();

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] { Site.getAdminEmail() };

        mail.setReplyTo('no-reply@salesforce.com');
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Chatter Answers User');

        // The default sender is the portal user causing this trigger to run, to change this, set an organization-wide address for
        // the portal user profile, and set the ID in the following line.
        // mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideEmailAddressId);
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject(subjectText);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(bodyText);
        if(!test.isrunningtest()){
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your unit test is working just fine. It's telling you there's a problem with your trigger. As it stands, you have at least three different problems with your trigger.

First, your code isn't bulkified. It can't handle large batches of records in a single transaction. If you think this will never apply to you, you're most likely wrong. You will eventually have a need to update records in bulk, and you won't be able to with this trigger.

You can fix this by moving the query outside the loop, and provide a variable for aggregating cases:

```
Question[] questions = 
    [SELECT Title, Body, CommunityId, createdById, 
            createdBy.AccountId, createdBy.ContactId, 
            (select id from cases) 
     FROM question where Id in :Trigger.new];
Case[] newCases = new Case[0];
```

You'll also want to reserve creating the cases until *after* the loop.

```
Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(newCases, false);
```

Second, your code will create cases when it shouldn't. This is because you check Question.Cases before you query for it. It will *always* be null, because relationships aren't automatically populated beforehand. The query above fixes this, but you'll need to change your for loop:

```
for (Question q: questions) {
```

Third, you're using a try-catch when you really shouldn't. As I just demonstrated above, use Database.insert(SObject[], false) to allow partial success. Afterwards, you should report any errors either by email (as you did), or by an actual error message. Here's an example:

```
for(Integer index = 0, size = newCases.size(); index < size; index++) {
    if(!results[index].isSuccess()) {
        Trigger.newMap.get(newCases[index].QuestionId).addError('Failed to create a case for this question.'));
    }
}
```

If you instead want to send an email, you can do the same type of logic; iterate over the list, find the errors, and email them.

---

Here's an approximation of how I'd write the code. This will fix the bulkification issues, but not the unit test.

```
trigger chatter_answers_question_escalation_to_case_trigger on Question (after update) {
    Case[] cases = new Case[0];
    for(Question record:[SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Cases), Title, Body, CommunityId, CreatedById, CreatedBy.AccountId, CreatedBy.ContactId 
                         FROM Question 
                         WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]) {
        if(!record.cases.isEmpty() && record.Priority == 'high' && Trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).Priority != 'high') {
            cases.add(
                new Case(
                    Origin = 'Chatter Answers', QuestionId = record.Id, CommunityId = record.CommunityId,
                    Description = record.Body == null? null: record.Body.stripHtmlTags(),
                    AccountId = record.CreatedBy.AccountId, ContactId = record.CreatedBy.ContactId
                )
            );
        }
    }
    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(cases, false);
    String[] errors = new String[0];
    for(Integer index = 0, size = cases.size(); index < size; index++) {
        if(!results[index].isSuccess()) {
            errors.add(
                String.format('Case for question {0} was not created; the first error reported was: {1}', 
                              new String[] { cases[index].QuestionId, results[index].getErrors()[0].getMessage() }));
            /* Uncomment me for testing purposes
            Trigger.newMap.get(cases[index].QuestionId).addError(results[index].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
            */
        }
    }
    if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setToAddresses( new String[] { Site.getAdminEmail(); });
        email.setReplyTo('no-reply@salesforce.com');
        email.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Chatter Answers User');
        email.setSubject('Case escalation errors in site '+Site.getName());
        email.setPlainTextBody(String.join(errors, '\n'));
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
    }
}
```

For *testing purposes*, I'd suggest allowing the exception to float up to the question. Uncomment the code marked above to see what the error is, then re-comment it once you figure it out. You will need to change your trigger based on the error. Most likely it is a validation rule or required field error.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Will you do me a favor and repost the trigger code all together?  I didnt write this trigger.  It was already written by Salesforce when I enabled Chatter Answers.  Thank you sooo much for the help. :)

Comment: @LisaWhitacre Here you go. Note that you'll need to do some additional work-- Fixing the trigger will simply expose the error.